# Null value in column violates not-null constraint after deleting objects incorrectly

Tags: django

Help me please I don't know what's going on.
I wrote some simple blog, where I could add posts and comments. It was working well.

views.py:

```
def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk) # calls the given model and get the object, type = <class 'blog.models.Post'
    if request.method == "POST": # if we posted data
        form = CommentForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): # if all fields are filled
            comment = form.save(commit=False) # create instance and return which not saved in database "Comment" <class Comment>
            comment.post = post # return Title
            comment.author = request.user
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm() # type = <class 'blog.forms.CommentForm'>
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})
```

But when I added a function for deleting comments, that wrote me a mistake, like this:

> null value in column "approved_comment" of relation "blog_comment"
> violates not-null constraint

views.py:

```
def comment_remove(request, pk):
       post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
       comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
       print(comment)
       comment.delete()
       return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
```

I think I deleted comment incorrectly. I don't understand how primary keys works, how comments and posts are related each other. And I don't understand how to understand it.

ps.
models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
related_name="author_name",
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

def publish(self):
    self.published_date = timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def approved_comments(self):
    return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-published_date']

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False),
    # parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, 
related_name='replies')

def approve(self):
    self.approved_comment = True
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.text, self.author)
```

pps. forms.py:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Comment
from django import forms
from .models import Post, Comment

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'text',)

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text',)
```

Comment: Hey Sergo, Please add your Model `Post's` defination in your question along with other supporting models' definations you have used.

Comment: Hi, Jyothi. I have added.

Comment: Hey @Sergo can you post the full error traceback.

Comment: The above exception (null value in column "approved_comment" of relation "blog_comment" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (18, Kakashi, 1, 2022-05-18 12:31:39+00, null, 6). ) was the direct cause of the following exception:
d:\Projects\Python projects\2. Django_projects\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 55, in inner
                response = get_response(request)

Comment: Hey Sergo, your model definition looks fine. Delete all the entries in the table and try  adding and deleting your comments. Also share your code for `CommentForm`.

Comment: Shared forms.py. I couldn't add some comments after when I deleting comments via def comment_remove. I think I have broken something in database. Also, I couldn't add via admin panel, but I could have. Did I need to delete all posts and all comments in admin panel manually?

Comment: You use same pk in `comment_remove` for getting `Post` and `Comment`. That could not be correct.

Comment: Marco, hey, I remembered that I used git, so I tryed git reset .. And now it's work. Then I tryed again with deleting comments and understood too that the main problem with my misunderstandings how pk works. So, I will try to understand it. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

> To understand how to delete comments we need to understand how pk(primary keys) and related_name works.

> Let's see model class Comment. Pay attention for post and related_name='comments' and than see it in post_detail.html.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

post_detail.html:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk %}">Add comment</a>
    {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
        <div class="comment">
            <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
            <div class="date">{{ comment.created_date }}</div>
            <strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>
            <p>{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No comments here yet :(</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

> post.comments.all - post is relating for model our Post model. The related_name specifies the name of the relation in reverse, so in this case accessing the Comment of a given Post object. [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name]
> Now you know how we get comment.pk.

After that  please pay attention how we're removing comment.
views.py:

```
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)
```

> Look at the comment.post.pk. In our Comment model we have key post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments'), which is relating with our Post Model. That's it!